# Replacing the address on the click of a button laravel

Tags: laravel

Suppose the user is on one page that has its own URL, on the same page there is a button addressing to another page, but two URLs appear in the address, how to make the address change?

Answer (score -1):

Try this one

```
<a href="url" class="btn btn-primary"> Button Name </a>
```

OR :

```
    <button class="btn btn-primary"><a href="url"> Button Name</a></button>
```

Comment: `<button>` inside `<a>` is invalid

Comment: But we can use `<a>` inside the `<button>` tag. or first answer is correct. @brombeer

Comment: No, you cannot use `<a>` inside a `<button>` (if it has a `href`)